# GHC.Generics or Data.Data?

Tags: generics, haskell

There are currently 2 (3 if you count TemplateHaskell) options for generic programming using GHC, [Data.Data](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Data.html) / [Data.Typeable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html) and [GHC.Generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/GHC-Generics.html), both available from the base package. So, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Is GHC.Generics the "modern" way and Data.Data obsolete and just kept for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

GHC.Generics is the modern way and it is much faster than SYB. It however exposes a different approach to generic programming to the end user, so I don't think that it should be thought of as a direct replacement of SYB, though it does solve the same problems.

A good example of how those approaches differ from user's perspective can be extracted from the [aeson library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/)'s functionality of serialization of a record to JSON:

### Without generics

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Aeson

data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Double }

instance ToJSON Coord where
   toJSON (Coord x y) = object ["x" .= x, "y" .= y]
```

And use [`toJSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson.html#v:toJSON) of `ToJSON` typeclass afterwards.

### Using GHC.Generics

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Aeson    
import GHC.Generics

data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Double } deriving Generic

instance ToJSON Coord
```

And use the same [`toJSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson.html#v:toJSON) of `ToJSON` typeclass afterwards.

### Using SYB

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Aeson.Generic

data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Double } deriving (Data, Typeable)
```

And use a specific [`toJSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson-Generic.html#v:toJSON) from `Data.Aeson.Generic` with the following signature:

```
toJSON :: Data a => a -> Value
```

Comment: I don't think they differ from the users experience much, I can also use default signatures with SYB and derive Typeable/Data instead of Generic. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: When you say `Generics` are much faster, is that compile time or run time faster?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov The difference in aeson is just what is used as default. One could similar make a default signature using Data and Typeable, and then write instance ToJson Coord, after deriving Data and Typeable.

Comment: @bennofs Sure. However you can't do the inverse, i.e. get around without typeclasses using GHC.Generics.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov could you add some reference re "GHC.Generics is the modern way and it is much faster than SYB"? I'm new and curious.

Comment: I have the same question. I've spent 2 days on generics-sop and then another 2 days on Generic.GHC and just a few hours on Data.Data, and found the latter the easiest to use and understand. What's the downside of building generic functions using Typeable and Data?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda The main downside is performance. SYB is slower

Comment: @SaurabhNanda, I think one of the biggest downsides is that `Data.Data` requires that all fields be `Data` instances. Sometimes that's what you want; very often it's not. With `GHC.Generics`, you have very fine control over what class constraints you need where. As for performance, `GHC.Generics` generally does very well with product types. For sum types, it's often a big fight between you and the optimizer. For compositions (with `Generic1`) performance can be very bad under certain circumstances due to a design mistake.